# Adding multiple products to spree cart with single click

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I'm using spree 3.0 with ROR 4, and in our ecommerce site we want to be able to make recommendations to our customers for pairing of items. like shirt pants combinations. so the customer will answer a couple of questions and then we show them a list of product combinations (taxons i would assume), but then when they click on the choice, its takes them to a page with BOTH items where they can choose the size of each item individually, but add them both to the cart with ONE click 'add to cart'. has anybody solved this with spree yet?

Comment: You can use the Spree API to add multiple line_items to an order.

Comment: Spree::Core comes with some example Promotions-actions, one of them is to "Create Line Items". This may be a good place to start looking as an example on how to add stuff to a cart based on conditions. I would not advice to use promotions for your feature though. My advice is to look at it for inspiration.

Comment: @gmacdougall So i could modify the view page to show multiple items, where the user could choose their sizes in the various products, then have an 'Add Both' button which would use the API to add multiple line items?  is that the approach you would recommend?

Comment: @radamnyc Yes, that's what I would do.